# Cast a BytesWritable to com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry

Tags: java, geometry, byte

I have variable in byteswritable, however I would like to use com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry , to cast it to a geometry but I don't know who to procede.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your problem but ... what is the link between bytes and geometric figures ?

Comment: @Lutzi I want to create a geometry out of a array of bytes, If you are familiar with postgis which is a spatial extension of postgres (database), if you were to create a point there, like this ST_Point(25,45) the result that you get is like this : 010100000000000000000039400000000000804640